# Age-verifying regex that should reject 3-digit numbers that begin with zero returning something strange

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to write a piece of regex code that verifies an age that has 1,2, or 3 digits for a simple form.  If it has 3 digits, the leading digit must be a 1, and the leading digit is never 0.

What I have so far:

`/^1[0-9][0-9]$|^[0-9][0-9]$|^[0-9]$/`

An example of this odd behavior:

```
> myRe = /^1[0-9][0-9]$|^[0-9][0-9]$/;
> myRe.exec(023);
["19"]
> myRe.exec(052);
["42"]
```

Comment: Ignoring the octal problem, why not check if the number is smaller than 999 (i.e. 3 long), then check that the first is 1 and not 0? That seems cleaner than a slightly opaque regex.

Comment: @RichBradshaw This is for an assignment on JavaScript and form validation with regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for all of the quick, helpful responses!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wouldn't recommend doing it like this in real life though. Did you know that you can write `<input pattern='$REGEX_GOES_HERE$' />`, then in new browsers you won't be allowed to submit the form unless it matches?

Comment: @RichBradshaw Interesting! Is that supported in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`023` is a number, and regular expressions don't work on numbers. So JavaScript converts the number into a string first. And because of the zero, it is an octal number; so 023 is actually `2 * 8 + 3`, and not `2 * 10 + 3`.

You want to do `myRe.exec("023")` instead. Also, you might want to modify your regex so that the first digit in the double-digit branch and the single digit in the last branch read `[1-9]`, and not `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you start a number literal with 0 it's interpreted as octal (base 8). So 052 (base 8) is actually 42 (base 10). Which is then converted to string ("42") and regexed.

As far as your regex goes: I'd improve it a bit like so:

```
/^1[0-9][0-9]$|^[1-9][0-9]$|^[0-9]$/
```

Answer (score 1):

In the expression

```
myRe.exec(023);
```

`023` is an octal number. What you want to check is a string. So enclose it in quotes

`/^1?\d{1,2}$/` - and here is a shorter and more readable version of the same regex.

Or `/^1?\d?\d$/` whichever you like more.

Answer (score 0):

You're appplying your RegExp against a number. RegExps expect a string argument.

Therefore:

```
> myRe = /^1[0-9][0-9]$|^[0-9][0-9]$/;
> myRe.exec('023');
null
> myRe.exec('23');
["23"]
> myRe.exec('052');
null
> myRe.exec('52');
["52"]
```

As expected.